# Packing repeated bytes in protobuf-c

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

So I'm trying to serialize a struct containing a byte array and its size:

```
struct Msg {
    unsigned char* payload;
    size_t payload_size;
};
```

the following code uses an instance of this struct called `msg`.

```
    DiagResp resp  = DIAG_RESP__INIT;

    ProtobufCBinaryData payload;
    payload.data = msg->payload;
    payload.len = msg->payload_size;

    resp.payload = &payload;
    resp.n_payload = msg->payload_size;

    resp.has_payload_size = 1;
    resp.payload_size = msg->payload_size;

    size_t packed_size = diag_resp__get_packed_size(&resp);
    printf("packed_size=%lu, msg->received_bytes=%lu\n", 
           packed_size, msg->received_bytes);
    *ret_payload = malloc(packed_size);
    diag_resp__pack(&resp, *ret_payload);
```

this is from the `.proto` file:

```
message DiagResp {
  ...
  optional int32 payload_size = 10;
  repeated bytes payload = 11;
}
```

The `printf` call prints out this:

```
packed_size=4256922, msg->received_bytes=4
```

...but if I don't attempt to serialize the `payload` field, everything works as expected. So how do I serialize a `repeated bytes` field? It is not covered in the `protobuf-c` documentation...

Comment: I may have it - for some reason, setting `resp.n_payload` makes protobuf-c glitch out completely. If I leave it unset, it seems to work ok...

Comment: I can't help with protobuf-c, but I wanted to comment that encoding `payload_size` as a second field is redundant here. Protobuf already keeps track of the size for a `bytes` field.